# Why doesn't a stack overflow always occur?

Tags: java, memory, stack-overflow

I'm currently studying Java and, as a part of my learning, I attempted to intentionally induce a stack overflow to see what it would do.

I did some boundary testing and, interestingly, I discovered that if I execute the following code it will only sporadically cause an error. Sometimes it will run without any problems.

```
public class SO
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ohno(0);
    }

    public static void ohno(int a)
    {
        System.out.println(a);
        if (a != 11413)
            ohno(a+1);
    }
}
```

My questions are as follows:

- What might be causing my stack size to vary between executions of this very simple example?
- These days, does a stack overflow always occur due to poor code design (i.e. infinite recursion, excessively large primitives, etc.) or are there real world scenarios where the stack is still a technical limitation?
- This one may seem obvious but.. does increasing the physical memory of a system also increase the size of the stack?

Comment: As for the last question: No. First of all, regarding the Java aspect, remember that Java is a "virtual machine" that is independent of the actual system it's running on. That means it will handle its own stack and keep it separate from the normal OS/hardware stack. Secondly, the underlying operating system usually have a fixed size of the stack for its processes, so adding more memory will not increase the stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Limited stack size is a function of how much memory you allocate to the JVM.

Resource-constrained systems have less memory that *can* be allocated, so absolutely there are real-world scenarios where stack size is a limitation, and there are times where you have to use iterative solutions to naturally-recursive problems as a result.

Increasing the physical memory of a system only matters if you allow that memory to be allocated by the JVM, otherwise you'll get the defaults of that platform.

Answer (score 1):

The chance of occurring the StackOverflowException is depending on how much memory you have assigned, by using the parameters XmxM/G for the maximum memory and XmxS/G for the least.

Stack overflow could be happening on any situation, if there is a dead loop, or would have potential to get this by self looping with a large sum(that drains a lot of memories) of data.

Answer (score 0):

Many compilers detect tail recursive calls and reuse the same stack frame for that call, thus preventing the such calls from growing the stack. A tail recursive call is one where the recursive call is the last instruction in a method or function. This optimization lets you use tail recursion without worrying about stack overflow.

If you *want* to induce an overflow, try adding some code after the recursive call to prevent the optimization. You might have to play with it a bit -- good compilers are crafty and may be able to subvert simple attempts.